# Переменные в SQL запросе (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, redbeanphp

Доброго времени суток.
Вопрос может глупый, но правда гугл мне не может помочь (может запрашиваю не так, может ещё, что)
есть SQL запрос, который заканчивается на
`LIMIT 0, 3`
мне нужно вместо 0 и 3 подставить переменные, подскажите как это сделать, не могу даже про бинды типа :var1, :var2 найти.

(проблема ещё в том, что запрос обрамлён в одинарные кавычки, а не двойные, по этому некоторые вещи из интернета, тоже не катят)

Comment: мне будет достаточно ссылки на учебник/обсуждение и т д и т п, где я смогу найти информацию по биндам или вставке переменных в sql запросы

Comment: Смотрите PDO и подготовленный запросы

Comment: пишу на RedBean PHP 
` 
LIMIT :var1, :var2'); 


$some = $select->execute([
    "var1" => 0,
    "var2" => 3
]); 
`

думал такое прокатит... но нет

Comment: замените одинарные кавычки на двойные, какая разница? И прочтите документацию, особенно разделы [Finding](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/finding) и [Querying](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/querying)

Comment: Замена на двойные даст ошибку синтаксиса, а разделы - почитаю.

Comment: LIMIT :var1, :var2, [':var1' => '1', ':var2' => '3']'); - не работает
LIMIT :var1, :var2'); $some = $select->execute([ "var1" => 0, "var2" => 3 ]); тоже не работает...
LIMIT ?, ? [$var1,[$var2]] собственно как и это...

я видимо абсолютно не понял как этим пользоваться, или одно из двух

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в итоге следующее ( может не идеальное, но рабочее)

```
 $binds = [
     'var1' => $var1,
     'var2' => $var2
 ];


$select = = ('SELECT...WHERE... LIMIT :var1, :var2');

$result = R::getAll($select, $binds);
```